# Google guice: help to inject

Tags: java, guice

I need some help to use guice.
I've my project here: https://github.com/Romain-P/kalibro/blob/master/realm/src/org/kalibro/core/Main.java

My problem: I need to replace in this Main.java the 3 injectors, with just 1 injector.

My application is separated: 
LoginServer and WorldServers.
You have just 1 realmServer, and some WorldServers as you want.

Now, I've just created realmServer. In it you have:
- RealmManager (which manages players <-> loginServer)
- ExchangeManager (which manages worlds <-> loginServer)

They accept connexions, and they create clients, with netty.
RealmManager & ExchangeManager extend NetworkService.

NetworkService is an abstractClass, which is useful to create all managers as you want. Imagine if i want later to create shopManager, which speaks with webServer.

Please see the code: https://github.com/Romain-P/kalibro/tree/master/realm/src/org/kalibro/network/netty

Now, my Main.java has 3 injectors, but i need to have just 1.
That does work ! but i think it's not cleaned, so i need to have just 1 Injector.

Main.java

```
[...]
Injector exchangeInjector = Guice.createInjector(new ExchangeModule());
Injector realmInjector = Guice.createInjector(new RealmModule());
try {
    log.info("initializing exchange");
    exchangeInjector.getInstance(ExchangeManager.class).run(config.getExchangePort());
    log.info("initializing server");
    realmInjector.getInstance(RealmManager.class).run(config.getRealmPort());
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Can't start application", +e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Modules:

```
public class RealmModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        install(new NetworkModule());
        bind(NetworkService.class).to(RealmManager.class);
    }
}
//the same for ExchangeModule..
```

Comment: Do you need to bind both to `NetworkService`? You resolve instances using the concrete classes - can you get away with just binding to the concrete classes, e.g. `bind(RealmManager.class);`, in the module? Then both modules can be created in a single injector.

Comment: it's not possible, because i @inject networkService in networkServiceHandler, and he will don't know what manager use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guice injector has ... array as an argument:

```
Guice.createInjector(Module... modules);
```

So you can simply do:

```
Guice.createInjector(new ExchangeModule(), new RealmModule());
```

If there are some conflicts you can try [binding annotations](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)  or [untargetted bindings](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings).

EDIT:

This might show how you could avoid conflicts:

```
bind(NetworkService.class).annotatedWith(Exchange.class).to(ExchangeManager.class);
bind(NetworkService.class).annotatedWith(Realm.class).to(RealmManager.class);
```

then:

```
@Inject
@Exchange
private NetworkService exchangeService;
```

EDIT 2:

I think the greatest problem is the way you initiate the NetworkService. You can make it an abstract class and then write something like that:

```
public class ExchangeHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Inject
    ExchangeHandler(@Exchange NetworkService service) {
         super(service);
    }
}
```

You want to have 2 distinct instances that use the exactly same code except for obtaining the NetworkService instance. There are several ways to do it but this one seems to be the most readable at the moment. Alternatively you might consider using Inversion of Control to pass NetworkService you need at the moment instead of creating 2 distinct trees of objects for `Exchange` and `Reaml` managers.

```
class ClassUsingManagers {
    @Inject
    ClassUsingManagers(
            @Exchange NetworkService exchangeService,
            @Realm NetworkService realmService,
            NetworkServiceHandler handler) {
        handler.actionForService(exchangeService);
        handler.actionForService(realmService);
    }
}
```

or if you just want to initiate them and run one method (which initialized everything else):

```
Multibinder serviceSet = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), NetworkService.class);
serviceSet.addBinding().asEagerSingleton();
```

an then:

```
class ClassUsingManagers {
    @Inject
    ClassUsingManagers(
            Set<NetworkService> services,
            NetworkServiceHandler handler) {
        for(NetworkService service : services)
            handler.actionForService(service);
    }
}
```

That other method would require you to install Guice Multbinding addon to Guice.

Comment: I've added example to show how you could achieve your goal.

Comment: thank you but that don't fixe my problem :] cause i need to @Inject NetworkService in NetworkServiceHandler, and he must be NetworkService without annotation, cause it's an "interface" wich is used to create new services.. example, i will maybe add shopManager

Comment: If it still not what you need, please describe exactly what you want to achieve with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a binding [annotation](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) to distinguish the injections of NetworkService, perhaps:

```
  @ManagesExchange NetworkService
  @ManagesRealm NetworkService
```

Comment: In your binding (see the wiki: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)

Comment: it's not what i need, sorry